# Cómo obtener los 3 valores mas altos en columnas?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Hola amigos pregunto si es posible obtener 3 valores mayores de un conjunto y mostrarlos en columnas es decir que la tabla estaría de la siguiente forma: ValorMayor1, ValorMayor2, ValorMayor4.  Es posible obtener así los resultados. Mi consulta hasta ahora:

Mi problema es que me muestra los resultados de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    SELECT id_alumno, resultado, id_perfil FROM puntajes WHERE 
resultado >= IFNULL((SELECT resultado FROM puntajes AS p2 WHERE 
p2.id_alumno = puntajes.id_alumno ORDER BY resultado DESC 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2), 0) ORDER BY puntajes.id_alumno, resultado DESC
```

Y los quiero tener los tres resultados en columnas cómo hago eso? **resultado1, resultado2 y resultado3.**

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla a la que le realizo la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los resultados **exactos** que quieres. Pon un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener, porque no se entiende del todo en la pregunta. Ni siquiera dices cuál es la columna de la que quieres obtener el resultado mayor, si se debe operar una suma sobre los datos, etc.

Comment: Ok amigo gracias por responder, espéreme.

Comment: Quizás sirva algo como SELECT MAX(valor1) FROM puntajes UNION ALL SELECT MAX(valor2) FROM puntajes UNION ALL SELECT MAX(valor3) FROM puntajes

Comment: Amigo gracias por intentarlo pero no es lo que quiero. Gracias. Eso no funciona.

Comment: Ok Diego, mira este link (https://revistadigital.inesem.es/informatica-y-tics/convertir-filas-en-columnas-y-columnas-en-filas-en-sql-server/) Es de SQLServer, pero quizás MySQL tiene algo parecido.

Answer (score 1):

Ahora que has explicado con claridad lo que quieres:

> ... solo quería que cada id_alumno le mostrara sus 3 resultados mas
>   altos. Ejemplo alumno 1 tiene 9,8,7,6,5 entonces le muestro 9,8 y 7 y
>   así sucesivamente con los demás alumnos, alumno 2, alumno 3 etc

Propongo esta solución simple que consiste en una combinación de `SUBSTRING_INDEX` y `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Lo que hace la consulta es agrupar la columna `resultado` por cada `id_alumno`, en el `GROUP_CONCAT` ordenamos por `resultado` y nos valemos de `SUBSTRING_INDEX` para obtener solamente tres resultados (que serían los mayores)  por cada grupo.

Lo único es que no te mostrará los tres valores en tres columnas como querías. Pero si los datos van a ser manejados en un lenguaje de programación cualquiera, se podría explotar el separador `,` para obtener cada valor como un dato individual.

Si esta solución no te sirve, entonces habría que simular algo parecido a la función `ROW_NUMBER()` de otros manejadores de bases de datos, la cual no existe en MySQL.

Entonces, la consulta sería esto sencillamente.

```
SELECT 
    id_alumno, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(resultado ORDER BY resultado DESC SEPARATOR ',' ), ',', 3) as resultados
FROM puntaje 
GROUP BY id_alumno;
```

Y los resultados vendría así, tres valores separados por coma que serían los resultados más altos por cada alumno:

```
id_alumno       resultados
---------------------------
1               53,52,51
3               56,52,48
4               12,10,10
```

Otra ventaja que esto tendría es que si un alumno tiene menos de tres resultados la consulta no va a fallar, te presentará solamente los valores que tenga, aunque sean menos de tres.

---

### Código de prueba

Puedes ver aquí una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](http://rextester.com/edit/DUAP90422)**</kbd> de los datos de prueba que fueron usados para reproducir la situación.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Amigo gracias por tu respuesta pero no veo donde especificas el id_alumno sea = 3 ?  Solo me muestra ese registro y lo que quiero es obtener de todos los id_alumno. Daré mas detalles de la tabla a la que le realizo la consulta.

Comment: ¿Probaste la consulta? Te traerá los tres valores más altos independiente del alumno.

Comment: si me trae los 3 valores mas altos pero solo del id_alumno = 3.  Y no veo donde cambiarle el numero del id??

Comment: @DiegosSánchez según he entendido y por la imagen que has puesto, lo que querías era traer los resultados más altos sin importar el `id_alumno`,  en el ejemplo que pones de hecho los tres resultados parecen ser del mismo alumno. Si se trata de agrupar entonces tiene más lógica y sería más fácil hacerlo, pero no dices nada de ello en el planteamiento de la pregunta.

Comment: Perdón amigo es que anda mi cabeza en resolver esto y no me había dado cuenta pero si efectivamente se repiten los id_alumno pero son diferentes los resultados ya que debe obtener los 3 mayores en columnas jejejeje.

Comment: @Pero debes decir si los datos van agrupados por `id_alumno`, o sea, si quieres los tres mayores y cada  `id_alumno` debe ser diferente en esos tres resultados, @DiegosSanchez

Comment: Amigo el id_alumno siempre se repetirá 9 veces porque el alumno tiene 9 perfiles y a cada perfil le pertenece un resultado, es por eso que el resultado puede variar o repetirse con algunos.

Comment: No es eso lo que quiero saber, sino si lo que quieres es obtener los tres mayores resultados sin importar que id de alumno sea. En tu ejemplo parece ser eso lo que quieres, y la consulta que te muestro eso es lo que hace, pero luego dices que no funciona. Entonces no comprendo bien qué es lo que quieres. Así va a ser imposible ayudarte si no aclaras cómo tienes los datos y el resultado que quieres. En el ejemplo los valores 56, 52 y 48 pertenecen al mismo alumno... no entiendo tampoco lo que comentas sobre los perfiles. Creo que debes editar la pregunta tratando de explicar las cosas claras.

Comment: Esta bien amigo comprendo y gracias por tratar de ayudarme solo quería que cada id_alumno  le mostrara sus  3 resultados mas altos. Ejemplo alumno 1 tiene 9,8,7,6,5 entonces le muestro 9,8 y 7 y así sucesivamente con los demás alumnos, alumno 2, alumno 3 etc. Si no me doy a entender ok amigo gracias por todo.

Comment: @DiegosSánchez no fue hasta tu último comentario que puede entender exactamente lo que querías. Revisa la nueva respuesta, la cual ofrece una posible solución. Si vas a tratar los datos en cualquier lenguaje de programación será fácil explotar los datos como valores individuales usando el separador `,`. De lo contrario, habría que emular una función `ROW_NUMBER` que no existe en MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a una estructura [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table). El problema es que de todo lo que he buscado en todos los ejemplos hay **3** campos necesarios para ejecutar esto, en tu deberían ser caso serian:

- id_alumno
- numResultado ( el que te falta);
- resultado

Para ejecutar esta forma de estructuracion necesitarias una estructura tal que asi

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+
| id_alumno  | numResultado | resultado |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|     1      |      1       |    20     |
|     1      |      2       |    10     |
|     1      |      3       |    18     |
|     2      |      1       |    42     |
|     2      |      2       |    35     |
|     2      |      3       |    18     |
|     3      |      1       |    11     |
|     3      |      2       |    45     |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Siendo `numResultado` el indice de cada nota:

- Nota 1 del alumno 1 = 20
- Nota 2 del alumno 1 = 10
- Nota 3 del alumno 3 = 18
- ...
- Nota 2 del alumno 3 = 45

Para llegar a este resultado puedes reestructurar tu tabla o hacer un `Select` que te lo deje de esta forma

> Esto es necesario ya que de momento todos los ejemplo encontrados hacen uso de una estructura similar.

Teniendo esto ya puedes ejecutar la `Select` utilizando la metodologia `pivot`:

> Hay bases de datos como SQLServer por ejemplo que lo tienen implementado como funciones sin emabrgo en otros como MySQL solo se llama de esta forma a la forma de estructurarlo

```
SELECT 
 id_alumno,
 SUM(numResultado=1) AS "Nota1",
 SUM(numResultado=2) AS "Nota2",
 SUM(numResultado=3) AS "Nota3"
FROM table -- SI es una select en vez de tabla seria [FROM (SELECT...) AS reestructuracion]
GROUP BY id_alumno
```

Esta consulta te dará el siguiente resultado:

```
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
| id_alumno | Nota1 | Nota2 | Nota3 |  
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1     |   20  |   10  |  18   |
|     2     |   42  |   35  |  18   |
|     3     |   11  |   45  |   0   |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Con poner `MySQL Pivot` en google encontraras muchos mas ejemplos aunque esto es de lo mas simple y claro que he encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

AMIGOS HE ENCONTRADO UNA MANERA DE TENER LOS 3 valores mas altos de cada grupo en mi caso id_alumno cada uno sus tres resultados mayores:  Investigando llegue a esto, no es mucho pero a alguien le puede servir, gracias a todos por ayudar:
Esta es eficiente en los duplicados ya que si tenemos 10,11,11,12,11,12  Lo que mostrara será:  12,12,11 y la que publique la de arriba me muestra los duplicados o sea: 12,12,11,11,11. Esta es mejor:

```
      SELECT id_puntaje, id_alumno, resultado FROM ( SELECT id_puntaje, id_alumno, resultado,
     @rn := IF(@prev = id_alumno, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn, @prev := id_alumno 
        FROM puntajes JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) 
AS vars ORDER BY id_alumno, resultado DESC, id_puntaje ) AS T1 WHERE rn <= 3;
```

Muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]